# Ubuntu Core works on Asus Tinker Board?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Ubuntu Core works great on Raspberry Pi 2 and 3. But Asus has a much better hardware offer with its Tinker Board.

Both are very similar visually and in hardware architecture.

I looked all over the web and found no one testing Ubuntu Core on the Tinker Board. Someone else has had this experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's armhf, so the architecture is supported. However, Ubuntu Core itself is only officially ported to a few select reference boards outlined [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started). As a result, while Ubuntu Core would likely run on the Tinker Board given the correct kernel features, someone would need to port it.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I will start some test to see the result.